# How to add CheckConstraint between related models

Tags: django, check-constraints

I want to add **CheckConstraint** which concerned different related models.

Users are attached in a particular site (research team/institute) for a given study/project. A user can only be attached to one site for a given study.

Sites can be involved or not in differents studies/projects.

I want to add a constraint that prevent User to be attached to a study and a site id this site is not involved in this study.

Below database model
[image]

Comment: You can't directly make constraints spanning relations. What you can do though is make a function in your database, [make an expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#writing-your-own-query-expressions) that uses this function and then use that in your constraint.

Comment: i do not understand what you suggest...